# how to do arrow sorting on columns

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement to do sorting. I did it with `sort()` but does only in ascending way. My client wants to have column sorting, how can I do this with my code?

```
public class PagingTasksController{

public List<Task> tasks;
public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
public String QueryString {get;set;}
public Integer OffsetSize = 0;
private Integer QueryLimit = 3;
public List<Task> lstTasks;
public String searchText {get;set;} 

public PagingTasksController (){
    //CountTotalRecords= [select count() from Task];
}



public List<Task> getTasks(){
    if(tasks == null){
        tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
    return tasks;
}

public void findTasks(){
    String qStr2 = 'Select count() from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
    CountTotalRecords = Database.countQuery(qStr2);
    queryTasks();
}

public void  queryTasks(){
    String qStr = 'Select OwnerId,Subject,Status,Priority from Task where Subject like \'%'+searchText+'%\' OR Status like \'%'+searchText+'%\' Order By Subject,Status limit ' + QueryLimit + ' offset ' + OffsetSize;
    tasks = Database.query(qStr);
    tasks.sort();

}

public Boolean getDisablePrevious(){
    if(OffsetSize>0){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

public Boolean getDisableNext() {
    if (OffsetSize + QueryLimit < countTotalRecords){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

public PageReference Next() {
    OffsetSize += QueryLimit;
    queryTasks();
    return null;
}

public PageReference Previous() {
    OffsetSize -= QueryLimit;
    queryTasks();
    return null;
}

  public PageReference save() {
    update tasks;
    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
 }

}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PagingTasksController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Tasks" id="pgBlock">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
           <apex:commandButton onclick="resetInlineEdit()" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel"/>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"
                hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"
                changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>

     <apex:inputText id="searchBox" value="{!searchText}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock" action="{!findTasks}"/>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Tasks}" var="tsk" id="pgTable" >
       <apex:column >
        <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Task.Delete, tsk.id,['retURL'='/apex/Task_Assignment_Features'])}" >Delete</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>

      <apex:column headerValue="Subject">
        <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Subject}"/>
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="Status">
         <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Status}"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:column headerValue="Priority">
        <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.Priority}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="OwnerId">
        <apex:outputField value="{!tsk.OwnerId}"/>
    </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Previous}" rerender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                status="status" disabled="{!DisablePrevious}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" reRender="pgTable,pgBlock"
                                status="status" disabled="{!DisableNext}" />
            <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Please Wait..."/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Activity" height="800" rowsPerPage="50" customizable="False"/>
```

Comment: It is usually simplest to add an "[order by](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm)" term to the SOQL with an "asc" or "desc" suffix for the direction rather than going the sorting in Apex. If you Google you will find many examples.

Comment: Keith, The requirement is to have an arrow column sorting which i seem will work with Jquery.I'm stucked here.

Comment: You do not need to use jQuery at all: you can add an apex:commandLink to the column heading and get your controller to do the work and then re-render. Here is one example of that: [A Recipe for Column Sorting](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/a-recipe-for-column-sorting-salesforce-visualforce-page). Client-side sorting (e.g. jQuery DataTables) is most effective when all the data can be queried at once so that all the work can be done at the client side.

Comment: Adding "please help," "this is urgent," etc is implicit in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of how you could implement sorting using some visualforce and apex. The trick here is an `apex:facet` tag, where you can set a link with some parameters. In this case it is a sort field name and the sort order. Every time a user clicks on the header link - the pageBlockTable is re-rendered with new attributes for the sort field and order:

Apex Class:

```
public class myClass{

    public String sortField {get;set;}
    public String myOrder {get;set;}
    public myClass(){
        // Default setting for the sorting
        sortField = 'CreatedDate';
        myOrder = 'DESC';
    }

    public List<Contact> getContacts(){

        String q = 'Select Id, FirstName, LastName From Contact ';
        q += ' Order by ' +  String.escapeSingleQuotes(sortField) + ' ' + myOrder + ' LIMIT 10';
        return Database.query(q);
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="con" id="myTable">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:commandLink value="FirstName" reRender="myTable">
                <apex:param name="sortField" value="FirstName" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                <apex:param name="myOrder" value="{!IF(myOrder == 'DESC', 'ASC','DESC')}" assignTo="{!myOrder}" />
                First Name
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!con.FirstName}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:commandLink value="LastName" reRender="myTable">
                <apex:param name="sortField" value="LastName" assignTo="{!sortField}" />
                <apex:param name="myOrder" value="{!IF(myOrder == 'DESC', 'ASC','DESC')}" assignTo="{!myOrder}" />
                Last Name
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputField value="{!con.LastName}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is to execute soql with 'ASC'/'DESC', you can add arrow for each column and execute 'Order by sorting column ASC/DESC' when the column is clicked.

Comment: Could you please suggest me an example for this ? I did not get you here.